# Getting the min and max values from a PHP array

Tags: php, performance, arrays

Is there a built in PHP function that will allow you get the minimum and maximum values from a PHP array?

If not, what's the most efficient way of doing this for the general case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[min](http://www.php.net/min) and [max](http://www.php.net/max).

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3);

$min = min($array);
$max = max($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Max](http://php.net/max)
[Min](http://php.net/Min)

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. [min()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) and [max()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)