# Remove Values from PHP Array if Present

Tags: php, arrays

**I have the following PHP array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 750
    [1] => 563
    [2] => 605
    [3] => 598
    [4] => 593
)
```

**I need to perform the following action on the array using PHP:**

1. Search the array for a value (the value will be in a
   variable; let's call it `$number`). If the value
   is present in the array, remove it.

If someone could walk me through how to do that, it would be much appreciated.

**Note:** If it makes it any easier, I can form the array so the keys are the same as the values.

Comment: For the god sake - read the documentation http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: These are 3 completely separate questions. Look at [Finding Min and Max](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428800/getting-the-min-and-max-values-from-a-php-array) questions for number 3.

Comment: OK, I've managed to find the min and max, and remove duplicates, but how do I remove a specific value if it exists? I'll edit the question to house only this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array_unique($array) // removes dupicate values


while(false !== ($num = array_search($num, $array))){
    unset($array[$num]);
}
$max = max($array);
```

will search for all keys with value $num and unset them

Comment: The while loop should check specifically for `!== false` because if the first element (index 0) is found, your code will not unset the element.

Comment: @genesis φ - Thanks for the answer. How do you feel `while` compares with Josh Randall's method of unsetting the key?

Comment: @stefmikhail: his one is little bit complicated and harder.

Comment: @genesis φ - Don't know if you saw my original question, but it was to explain how to remove duplicates as well as place the maximum value in a variable. How do you feel about Josh Randall's answer concerning those?

Comment: @stefmikhail: no, second step is wrong. I'll add it into my answer

Comment: @genesis φ - Thanks a bunch. I think this is at least the second time that you have helped me with a question. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @genesis φ - Just curious; What would happen if I didn't check if the value existed in the array before I tried to remove it? What if I just removed it?

Answer (score 2):

lets say your `$array`

```
$array = array_unique($array) // removes dupicate values

$array = arsort($array) 

$variable = $array[0]  //  the maximum value in the array, and place it in a variable.  

$key = array_search($array, $number);

if($key){

    unset($array[$key])  // Search array for a value, value is present in array, remove it.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_search()` and `unset()` seems a good method for your sample data in your question.  I'll just show a different way for comparison's sake (or in case your use case is slightly different from what you have posted here).

Methods: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a54cbe2d089e02a130d0a78f13585b2cb5f0b9cc))

```
$array=[750,563,605,598,593];

// if removing just one number apply the number as an array element
$number=605;
var_export(array_diff($array,[$number]));

// if you are performing this task with more than one $number, make $numbers=array() and do the same...
$numbers=[605,563];  // order doesn't matter
var_export(array_diff($array,$numbers));

// if you need to re-index the output array, use array_values()...
$numbers=[605,563];  // order doesn't matter
var_export(array_values(array_diff($array,$numbers)));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 750,
  1 => 563,
  3 => 598,
  4 => 593,
)

array (
  0 => 750,
  3 => 598,
  4 => 593,
)

array (
  0 => 750,
  1 => 598,
  2 => 593,
)
```